# My Model Rotates When Animated

Tags: animation, armature, transforms

I'm not too sure how to explain this. I've done the Alt+R to reset rotation, but when I am in pose mode, I move a bone, LocRot the whole armature, and the next frame it flips upside down. I have no clue why, and I can't find this online either. I've been searching for quite some time. I need to finish this animation, I have a deadline, but I can't figure this problem out and I'm too far to start over.
[image: Flipped]
[image: Normal]

Comment: just check what rotation you armature has on the key frame(s) after frame 90.

Answer (score 3):

Might be a quaternion rotation issue.... if your bone is performing a full rotation at some point you will find it had to make a reverse rotation to get back to where it started..   try a different rotation method..  Unfortunately it means you might have to start animating from scratch

Answer (score 2):

You should check the Dopesheet on the object and see if there are other animation frames on your thing (It sounds like there are).  If you see extra animation frames, you can delete them by selecting them and pressing <kbd>X</kbd>.